# Python pandas extracting numbers and text within text to two new column

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have the following text in column A:

```
  A   
hydrogen sulfide 7783-06-4  
none
chlorine 7782-50-5
```

I would like to extract only the numbers to another new column B and column C (next to A), e.g:

```
B
hydrogen_sulfide
none
chlorine 

C
7783-06-4
none
7782-50-5
```

Tried these

```
  import pandas as pd
    df["B"] = df["A"].str.extract("(\d*\)", expand=True)
    df["C"] = df["A"].str.extract("(d+)", expand=True)
    print(df)
```

Appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using pattern `([A-Za-z\s]+)([\d\-]+)`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ['hydrogen sulfide 7783-06-4', None, 'chlorine 7782-50-5']})
df[["B", "C"]] = df["A"].str.extract(r"([A-Za-z\s]+)([\d\-]+)")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                            A                  B          C
0  hydrogen sulfide 7783-06-4  hydrogen sulfide   7783-06-4
1                        None                NaN        NaN
2          chlorine 7782-50-5          chlorine   7782-50-5
```