# Extract numbers and text in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am new to Python Pandas, need your guidance. I have following below code which extract specific data from a pdf files and export into a excel file. The code is working fine, however all data are exported into text format. Is there any way I can use text and number extract in same code.

```
import os                        
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np              
import glob                      
import pdfplumber

def get_keyword(start, end, text):

for i in range(len(start)):
    try:
        field = ((text.split(start[i]))[1].split(end[i])[0])
        return field
    except:
        continue

   def main():
   my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
   for files in glob.glob("C:/PDFs\*.pdf"):
    with pdfplumber.open(files) as pdf:
        page = pdf.pages[0]
        text = page.extract_text()
        text = " ".join(text.split())

        # obtain keyword #1-Find Supplier-This is text & it is fine
        start = ['SUPPLIER ']
        end = [' Purchase']
        keyword1 = get_keyword(start, end, text)
        
        # obtain keyword #2-Find Invoice, This is number-which need to number not text.
        start = ['Invoice Weight(Kg) ']
        end = ['.00 Net Weight.(Kg)']
        keyword2 = get_keyword(start, end, text)

        my_list = [keyword1, keyword2]
        my_list = pd.Series(my_list)
        my_dataframe = my_dataframe.append(my_list, ignore_index=True)
        print("Document's keywords have been extracted successfully!")
        my_dataframe = my_dataframe.rename(columns={0:'Supplier',
                                                1:'Invoice Number',
                                                2:'Mill Lot Number'})
        save_path: str = 'C:/PDFs'
        os.chdir(save_path)

        # extract my dataframe to an .xlsx file!
        my_dataframe.to_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
        print("")
        print(my_dataframe)

       if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

I tried using #str.extract(r"([A-Za-z\s]+)([\d-]+)"))- but it did not work. I also tried below link, but could not decipher. Kindly help!!

[Python pandas extracting numbers and text within text to two new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62877069/python-pandas-extracting-numbers-and-text-within-text-to-two-new-column)

Comment: You can cast a columns to a specific type by using `astype`. e.g. my_dataframe['Invoice Number'].astype(int)

Comment: I tried keyword2= get_keyword.astype(int)(start, end, text) but it did not work. Error-AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: Are you saying that keyword2 is text and a number like **'Invoice 12345678'** and you only want the number, so 12345678 needs to be extracted from this value? You can do this with the keyword2 value as part of the **get_keyword** line using regex.